# Scala call-by-name constructor parameter in implicit class

Tags: scala, implicit, callbyname

The following code **does not compile**. Desired is to have a call-by-name constructor parameter in an implicit class as illustrated here,

```
def f(n: Int) = (1 to n) product

implicit class RichElapsed[A](val f: => A) extends AnyVal {

  def elapsed(): (A, Double) = {
    val start = System.nanoTime()
    val res = f
    val end = System.nanoTime()

    (res, (end-start)/1e6)
  }

}
```

where a call

```
val (res, time) = f(3).elapsed
res: Int = 6
time: Double = 123.0
```

This error is reported in REPL,

```
<console>:1: error: `val' parameters may not be call-by-name
       implicit class RichElapsed[A](val f: => A) extends AnyVal {
```

Thus to ask how `RichElapsed` class could be refactored.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter Schmitz's solution to simply drop the `val` (along with the hope of turning `RichElapsed` into a value class) is certainly the simplest and least intrusive thing to do.

If you really feel like you need a value class, another alternative is this:

```
class RichElapsed[A](val f: () => A) extends AnyVal {

  def elapsed(): (A, Double) = {
    val start = System.nanoTime()
    val res = f()
    val end = System.nanoTime()

    (res, (end-start)/1e6)
  }
}

implicit def toRichElapsed[A]( f: => A ) = new RichElapsed[A](() => f )
```

Note that while using a value class as above allows to remove the instantiation of a temporary `RichElapsed` instance, there is still some wrapping going on (both with my solution and with Peter Schmitz's solution).
Namely, the body passed by name as `f` is wrapped into a function instance (in Peter Schmitz's case this is not apparent in the code but will happen anyway under the hood).
If you want to remove this wrapping too, I believe the only solution would be to use a macro.

Comment: Many Thanks, chosen as preferred answer for its clarifying observations.

Answer (score 1):

Do it without `val` as the error messages demands and then you also have to abandon the `AnyVal` since a value class needs to have exactly one public val:

```
implicit class RichElapsed[A](f: => A)
```