# Macro variant of implicit class that allows for by-name argument

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-macros, callbyname

For a DSL, I want to introduce a `dup` extension method that basically calls `Vector.fill`, e.g.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.{IndexedSeq => Vec}

implicit final class Dup[A](private val in: A) extends AnyVal {
  def dup(n: Int): Vec[A] = Vector.fill(n)(in)
}

3 dup 4  // Vector(3, 3, 3, 3)
```

Now I want to make the argument a by-name value, so that the following would work correctly:

```
math.random dup 4  // wrong: four times the same value
```

I am looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103947/scala-call-by-name-constructor-parameter-in-implicit-class), so apparently there is no solution with a plain value class, only:

```
final class Dup[A](in: () => A) {
  def dup(n: Int): Vec[A] = Vector.fill(n)(in())
}
implicit def Dup[A](in: => A): Dup[A] = new Dup(() => in)

math.random dup 4   // ok
```

...undoing the advantage of a value-class that there is no boxing involved.

So I was wondering, would it be possible to write a macro that provides a no-instantiation solution where the argument is by-name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not?

```
// Doesn't matter if it's value class or not, code generated by macro
// will contain no references to it.
implicit final class Dup[A](in: A) {
  def dup(n: Int): Vec[A] = macro Macros.dupImpl[A]
}
object Dup {
  def dup[A](in: => A, n: Int) = Vector.fill(n)(in)
}
```

Macro impl:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object Macros {
  def dupImpl[A](c: blackbox.Context)(n: c.Expr[Int]): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val q"$conv($in)" = c.prefix.tree
    q"Dup.dup($in, $n)"
  }
}
```

The `c.prefix` can be assumed to contain a tree for the `in` argument wrapped in an implicit conversion (we can add some validation code and emit compilation error if it's not). We simply unwrap it and obtain the original tree that represents `in`. We then pass it directly to `Dup.dup` completely discarding implicit conversion in the finally generated code.

The only instantition left will be instantiation of `Function0` object that will be passed in place of by-name parameter, but this is unavoidable.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I edited from `class Macros` to `object Macros`, so this reflects the current macro API in Scala 2.11.

Comment: What was wrong with `class`? This was just a [macro bundle](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/bundles.html)

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about macro bundles; but it was not compiling with this new style for some reason, so I switched to the classical style.